# how to convert ISO 8601 timestamp to unix timestamp in scala

Tags: scala

For convert unix timestamp to ISO 8601, I'm using .toDateTime() method, what if I wanna convert ISO 8601 timestamp to unix timestamp in scala？

```
for {
JString(format) <- Some(format)
JInt(timestamp) <- Some(timestamp)
JString(timezone) <- Some(timezone)
res <- JString(new DateTime(timestamp.toLong).toDateTime(DateTimeZone.forID(timezone)).toString(format))
} yield res
res
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all - use `java.time` package which is based on Joda Time (use the later if you are on very old JVM which didn't have `java.time`). Your code looks like `java.sql` time functions - avoid them.

From your code it seems you want to take epoch and return formatted string and acknowledge timezone one the way.

Epoch to LocalDateTime:

```
java.time.LocalDateTime.ofEpochSecond(1587416590, 0, java.time.ZoneOffset.UTC)
```

these are: epoch seconds, nanoseconds and time offset.

To convert LocalDateTime to String yo need a format e.g.:

```
localDateTime.format(java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME)
```

if you have a target format defined as a string you can build formatted as:

```
val formatter = java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format)
```

All in all:

```
java.time.LocalDateTime.ofEpochSecond(
  epochSeconds,
  nanosIfYouHaveThem,
  offset
).format(java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(targetFormat))
```

If you want to do the opposite? You use:

```
java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(
  timestamp,
  format
).toEpochSecond(offset)
```

Comment: Hi Mateusz, if my date is 2020-04-20T19:30:16Z,  what should be the format and offset parameters in this, offset is "Z"?
java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(
  timestamp,
  format
).toEpochSecond(offset)

Comment: the Oracle docs have this covered https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html